# BOT Chat Framework error(404 not found)

Tags: botframework

I have hosted a simple BOT Chat on my IIS server, with URL being http://localhost:3978. But when i access http://localhost/3978/api/messages.  It throws error "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found". so when i am giving these as my end point in emulator , it s unable to connect and same message is displayed. Please anyone can help me on this

Comment: Unless you provide more details it will be impossible to help you. When you said you hosted your bot on IIS, does that means that you just did F5 in visual studio?

Comment: Is "localhost/3978" a typo or did you intend for that to be "localhost:3978" with the colon (:)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't conect because you need conect to http://localhost:3978/api/messages not http://localhost/3978/api/messages, if is failed and you are deploy in a IIS server, conect to http://localhost/api/messages

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting in IIS you want to enter either 
http://localhost/api/messages OR http://localhost/YourIISAppName/api/messages in the bot emulator. You can only use http://localhost:3879/api/messages if your code is running in visual studio and is set to run on PORT 3879 (which you can change in the properties of your bot application in VS). Also, make sure IIS is configured to accept POST requests.